# Facebook Like button class/id selector for CSS margin-bottom?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I can't seem to find the Facebook Like button's class or id to alter the CSS. I am interested in applying a margin-bottom to the button. I've tried looking in Chrome's Inspector but it doesn't seem to target it the button properly.

Comment: Could you share some relevant code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate dealing with those buttons. I just put them in a span then apply the "display:block" property to the span if I really need to fix it as a last resort. I got it working just fine below though.

http://jsfiddle.net/FLFyJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

The reason that makes you can't directly style a Facebook Like Button is that it's always inserted into the page as an iframe (whatever you use FBML, HTML5 or IFRAME code provided by Facebook).

The only way to style those buttons is to put them in a parent element (a div by example) and to style this element (opacity, margin, ...).

Comment: actually, dont do that. it's against facebook terms of use. read [IV. Application Integration Point](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) number 4d: "You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin."

well at least with opacity. margin is ok i guess.

Comment: Did i talked about "obscuring" or "covering" social plugins ? ... '-_-
The question was about "applying a margin-bottom to the button." ... i gave an answer ... i hardly see how a margin-bottom (may it be positive) could be against Facebook ToU ...

Comment: Opacity was just another example of what can possibly be done with an iframe as a child element, i'm not telling him to clickjack or whatever you may think about.